# Drupal - Shared Backend

Tags: iis

How can I, in Drupal, install a project that have 2 different websites(frontend) but share the same backend? Is it possible?

Comment: http://drupal.org/project/domain

Comment: Or for same code base but running on different databases you can try: http://drupal.org/documentation/install/multi-site

Answer (score 3):

Simple answer is **YES**. What you are trying to do can be achieved by using one of these modules:

1. The [Multi Site installation](http://drupal.org/documentation/install/multi-site) module (It requires separate database for each site or common database with table prefix.)
2. The [Domain Access](http://drupal.org/project/domain) module

These are just general suggestions, as there are several ways to achieve your goal. You have to choose the right method suited for your needs. [This](http://gotdrupal.com/videos/multisites-vs-multiple-sites) is a screen-cast which would be helpful for you.

Answer (score 1):

You should probably look at the [Domain Access](http://drupal.org/project/domain) module.

> The Domain Access project is a suite of modules that provide tools for running a group of affiliated sites from one Drupal installation and a single shared database. The module allows you to share users, content, and configurations across a group of sites.
>
> #### Technical background
>
> The module uses Drupal's Node Access system to determine what content is available on each site in the network. Unlike other multi-domain modules for Drupal, the Domain Access module determines user access based on the active domain that the user is viewing, rather than which group or site the user belongs to. For more information about Node Access in Drupal, see http://api.drupal.org/api/group/node_access/7.